# Not changing the color when the timer reaches a point

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following code:

```
initialize: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        min = parseInt($('#js-clock span').text()) - 1;
        $('#js-clock span').text(min + 'm');
        $('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').addClass('text-success');
        if(min > 3 && min < 0){
            $('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').removeClass('text-success');
            $('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').addClass('text-error');
        }else if(min == 0){
            alert('OMG');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Which affects the following html:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-large js-beacon-clock" id="js-clock">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>30m</span>
</div>
```

Counts down, alerts "OMG" when it reaches 0, great. But the `if (min > 3 && min < 0)` never executes, even when the timer gets to 2 ... 1 (when the clock should be red), instead it stays green.

I have even tried to do something like:

```
initialize: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        min = parseInt($('#js-clock span').text()) - 1;
        $('#js-clock span').text(min + 'm');
        if(min < 2){
            $('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').addClass('text-success');
        else if(min > 3 && min < 0){
            $('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').removeClass('text-success');
            $('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').addClass('text-error');
        }else if(min == 0){
            alert('OMG');
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

But then it never turns green and it never turns red. as it is, right now, its green but never turns red.

placing in the console: `$('.js-beacon-clock .fa-clock-o').addClass('text-success');` works as intended.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

There is no integer value for `min` that will make this true:

```
(min > 3 && min < 0)
```

Comment: that doesn't help me, what do you mean, no number fits here?

Comment: min can't be less than zero and greater than 3

Comment: @LogicLooking AKA: How can min be greater than 3 and also less than zero!

Comment: oops I might have those backwards.

Comment: @LogicLooking Ah that'll do it =D